# Job needed for French bank account?

Tags: france, banking

I am traveling in France for an extended period, just on holiday and probably staying to live after. Do I need a job to open a bank account here? I have UK and New Zealand passports and I have come here after living in NZ. I tried to open an account with Rhône-Alpes but they said I needed to be a student or have a job.

I have an address I can use so that is not a problem.

Comment: Yes and no, some banks do make it a requirement but it's also perfectly possible to open a bank account without a job. It's really up to the account manager at a particular branch, so if you know someone they have a relationship with or someone in your family is a good client, they are perfectly allowed to bend the “rules”. But if you just show up at a random bank, then chances are they will refuse. I don't know if you would have more luck with online banks or if some are perhaps more lenient than others. Hopefully someone else will be able to answer that.

Comment: One “solution” is just to phone them one by one. I had to do that when I needed to open an account in Switzerland (I was not a resident and had no employment in Switzerland – I needed it to get money as a freelancer – so that most banks weren't interested but I found one in the end).

Comment: You could just [get a very basic bank account, to which you have an automatic right](https://www.banque-france.fr/en/banque-de-france/missions/protection-du-consommateur/right-to-a-basic-bank-account.html)

Comment: @Gagravarr that right is enjoyed by residents of France, which probably explains the requirement to be a student or have a job.

Comment: @phoog [EU nationals are allowed to move to other countries whilst looking for a job](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=457), as well as for economically inactive people with more limits, so with a UK passport they shouldn't require a job to be resident

Comment: @Gagravarr, indeed, but moving for work or for studies is probably far more common -- and easier to prove -- than for job seeking or economic inactivity. If an EU citizen is in France for less than 90 days, she is enjoying her unrestricted right of residence for up to 90 days, so there's no need to prove anything, but maybe the banks want some sort of assurance that she plans to stay longer.

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation once upon a time.
French banks can initially refuse your business, but if you cannot find a bank then you can go to the Banque de France and ask them to assign you a bank.  (as Gagravarr suggested) They will pick one for you and that bank would then have to give you an account, free of charge, with no-charge basic services.  (bank card, so you can withdraw money from their bank machines and a chequebook).  Expect the assigned bank to look down their nose at you.  Prepare a few polite but pointed remarks about your rights if they give you a hassle.  They have three days to open the account for you.

The law in question is articles D312-5 and D312-6 of the Code Monétaire et Financier.  The only requirement is that you are a resident.

When you go to the Banque de France you'll need:

- Proof of residency (carte de séjour/nationalité)
- Proof you live somewhere, the famous "justicatif de domicile", which is usually a telephone or electricity bill no more than three months old.  Other documents are acceptable, you could call the BdF and ask before going there.
- An "attestation de refus", a document from a bank that says they won't give you an account.  The BdF wants proof that you at least tried.
- to fill out their request form, which is quite straightforward.

Go see www.banque-france.fr and look up "droit au compte," probably under the "particuliers" somewhere, to get more details and a copy of their request form.

Having said that I just went to La Poste (now le Banque Postale), which once upon a time was the government banque for people.  They gave me an real account, and with a smile and no hassle.  And I was "fresh off the boat," so to speak.  So I didn't have to go through the BdF.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need a job to open a bank account with a French bank.

As an example, the only requirements to open an account with a popular online bank are:

- aged 18 or older
- resident of France
- minimum initial deposit of 300
  euros

The requirements for asking a international Visa card are a bit more strict but do not require any income (either a 2500 euros positive balance on your account at the time of asking or an income of 1000 euros per month).

Reference: [Boursorama Banque](http://www.boursorama.com/aide/assistance/devenir-client/conditions/conditions-requises/quelles-sont-les-conditions-requises-pour-devenir-client--1659#assistance)

Comment: Do you have a source or reference for this?

Comment: Preferably you should name the bank and link to the page on their website which shows these requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to respond here but I want to say thanks for the answers. You were 100% correct in that a job is not needed. I opened an account with La Banque Postale including a credit card and they only required an Attestation D'Hebergement.